# Konva js viewport support?

Tags: viewport, konvajs

I am currently using Fabric JS but I dont like the layer/group implementation there but beside of layers fabric js has something useful I cannot find in konva js at the moment: viewports. How much work would it to implement zooming to a certain point (most often the mouse cursor) and also emit mouse events with transformed coordinates?

Use case: I would like to zoom in on a the top most layer and use drawing tools to draw on the zoomed area, so the mouse event coordinates need to fit accordingly.

Thank you :)!

Comment: Hi Martin. Viewport is a concept that you can implement with a layer and rect combination. and zooming at a point is getting the mouse co-ords then scaling and offsetting to the scaled mouse co-ords.  See the stage.scale() function in the docs at https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Stage.html#scale

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working just by using some demo code and one coordinate scaling, great!